# iOS 8.3 Mobile Safari disable emoji rendering

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, mobile-safari

Apple released iOS 8.3 recently.
They added a lot more Emojis and all of them are rendered in mobile safari now.
For Example ▶ will be rendered to an emoji icon.
is there a way to disable emoji rendering? For example via CSS or JavaScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can disable these on a character by character basis by using the proper variant glyph.

The following example will render the black right pointing triangle as emoji as no variant is specified.

```
&#x25b6;
```

However, if you specify the proper variant glyph you'll get the text.

```
&#x25b6;&#xfe0e;
```

Generally speaking, `&#xfe0e;` gets you the text version and `&#xfe0f;` or not otherwise specified gets you the emoji version.

See http://anthonyticknor.com/demos/emoji/ for an example in practice for the left arrow and the black heavy heart. I picked up most of what I did there from http://mts.io/2015/04/21/unicode-symbol-render-text-emoji/

Comment: Your first link requires a login.

Comment: @mm201sorry about, I was moving hosts. it's back up now.